# Loop inside a $.each() statement

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid, each

I'm having a `result` inside which there are 5 items. Now under certain conditions i have to push those items in an array and bind it in jqgrid as columns and rows. So i have to loop into the result(something like that). How can i do?

//Code:

```
var colname = [];
    var colHeader = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("LoadColumns", "Home"))',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        success: OnComplete,
        error: OnFail
    });
    function OnComplete(result) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each(result, function () {
            console.log(result.rows[i]);
           var currentRow = result.rows[i];
           colHeader.push(currentRow.Name);
          // alert(currentRow.Name);
           switch (currentRow.Datatype) {

                case 'int':
                    colname.push({ name: currentRow.Name, index: currentRow.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false, sorttype: 'int' });
                    break;
                case 'String':
                    colname.push({ name: currentRow.Name, index: currentRow.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true });
                    break;
                case 'DateTime':
                    colname.push({
                        name: currentRow.Name, index: currentRow.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true, sorttype: 'date',
                        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, datefmt: 'm-d-Y'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'dropdown':
                    if (currentRow.ValueList != null && currentRow.ValueList != '') {
                        var ValueListArray = currentRow.ValueList.split(" ");
                        var valueListItems = '';
                        $.each(ValueListArray, function (index, values) {
                            valueListItems = valueListItems + values + ":" + values + ";";
                        });
                    }
                    colname.push({
                        name: currentRow.Name, index: currentRow.Name, width: 200, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select',
                        editoptions: { value: valueListItems.slice(0, -1) }, stype: 'select'
                                , searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + valueListItems.slice(0, -1) }, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true
                    });
                    break;

            }

            i++;
        });
}
```

when i tried i'm getting only one value getting printed for 11 times.

Not sure where i'm wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: when using jquery's each it is far easier to do this: $.each(result, function(key,value){};
This way you can access each loop iteration as value.  You can see what I mean by console logging value or value.rows to see what I mean.  This way you dont need to keep track of i.

Comment: I think the way you are using the loop and increment i is actually the problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer, done something like this.

//Code:

```
 var colname = [];
    var colHeader = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("LoadColumns", "Home"))',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        success: OnComplete,
        error: OnFail
    });
    function OnComplete(result) {

        $.each(result.rows, function (inx,val) {

           colHeader.push(this.Name);

           switch (this.Datatype) {

                case 'int':
                    colname.push({ name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false, sorttype: 'int' });
                    break;
                case 'String':
                    colname.push({ name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true });
                    break;
                case 'DateTime':
                    colname.push({
                        name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true, sorttype: 'date',
                        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, datefmt: 'm-d-Y'
                    });
                    break;
                case 'dropdown':
                    if (this.ValueList != null && this.ValueList != '') {
                        var ValueListArray = this.ValueList.split(" ");
                        var valueListItems = '';
                        $.each(ValueListArray, function (index, values) {
                            valueListItems = valueListItems + values + ":" + values + ";";
                        });
                    }
                    colname.push({
                        name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 200, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select',
                        editoptions: { value: valueListItems.slice(0, -1) }, stype: 'select'
                                , searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + valueListItems.slice(0, -1) }, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true
                    });
                    break;

            }


        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are new in JavaScript language. The most people start with another language and have to use JavaScript language later. The problem is that JavaScript language is quite different as C++/C# or Java which is probably your current favorite language. I strictly recommend you to change the style of your JavaScript code. Don't use the same style which you use in your other favorite language.

First of all you should follow the name conversion which are standard in JavaScript language. You can see already from the text of you question that `OnComplete`, `OnFail` or `ValueListArray` have another color as `i` variable for example. The reason: names of variables having the first capital letter are used as **constructors** of objects only. So one use

```js
var d = new Date();
```

for example instead of `var d = Date();`.

In the same way you should not always trying to use `foreach` construct which you probably like in C#.   The current version of JavaScript don't have the construct. So the usage of

```
var i, rows = result.rows, n = rows.length, item;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    item = rows[i];
    // now you can work with item
}
```

is much more quickly as the usage of [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). You can see that I saved the values of `rows` property (`result.rows`) in a variable and I saved `rows.length` in the next variable instead of usage `rows.length` directly in `for` loop. It improves the performance too because don't optimize the code. It can be that the size of `rows` array will be changes or even that `length` property will be overwritten by your custom implementation inside of `for` body. So JavaScript don't make any code optimization and saving unchanged property value in a variable will improve the performance.

Even the usage of `colHeader` variable defined in **outer scope** of `OnComplete` function works slowly as working with local variable `colHeader`. Probably you can do all the work inside of `OnComplete` (after the loop `$.each`)? The current code makes `OnComplete` [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111200/315935). It works in other way like you good knows in C#. So I recommend you to invest your time in studding JavaScript language. The argument after which I decide to do this for me was the fact that JavaScript don't have block level variables and use function level variables instead. If one don't understand that then one can write and read the code which will be interpreted by JavaScript in absolutely another way as you think. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802966/315935) for more details.

One more remark about the code

```
colname.push({ name: currentRow.Name, index: currentRow.Name, width: 200,
    align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false, sorttype: 'int' });
```

and other close lines. jqGrid don't have any **data type**. On the other side one can use column templates (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935)) which can make your code shorter and more readable.